# Como validar los campos totales de una matriz que se carga a través de una medida en PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

intento generar un reporte que permita convertir unos importes de su moneda origen a otra moneda, para ello tengo dos tablas las cuales he importado a power bi, la tabla A contiene el importe y su moneda origen, la tabla B es una tabla de combinaciones: moneda origen, moneda destino y tipo de cambio. Para relacionarlas cree una tabla intermedia. [image: Imagen]

Cuando creo la medida multiplico el campo importe de la tabla A por el tipo de cambio de la tabla B. Adicional he creado un filtro con la moneda destino. Cuando jalo la medida en una matriz esta genera los montos de los detalles correctamente pero a nivel de totales me salen unos montos muy elevados y no la suma del detalle.

```
Medida = SUM(PRUEBA[Liquidacion])*SUM(TIPO_CAMBIO[TIPO_CAMBIO])
```

Mi consulta es como puedo validar o determinar porque salen esos totales elevados? he intentado calculando por fuera con la data pero no llego a esos valores, o si existe otra forma de obtener lo que requiero. Cualquier información, link o sugerencia se los agradecería.